# Recursive copy of a specific file type maintaining the file structure in Unix/Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync, cp

I need to copy all `*.jar` files from a directory maintaining the folder structure of the parent directories. How can I do it in UNIX/Linux terminal?
The command `cp -r *.jar /destination_dir` is not what I am looking for.

Comment: does the destination directory need to maintain the folder structure of the source directory?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`rsync` is useful for local file copying as well as between machines. This will do what you want:

`rsync -avm --include='*.jar' -f 'hide,! */' . /destination_dir`

The entire directory structure from . is copied to /destination_dir, but only the .jar files are copied. The -a ensures all permissions and times on files are unchanged. The -m will omit empty directories. -v is for verbose output.

For a dry run add a -n, it will tell you what it would do but not actually copy anything.

Comment: Would you mind explaining me this part: `-f 'hide,! */' `? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sure. The -f means it is a filter rule (short for --filter). The rule says hide all non-directories, ie files. The '\*/' pattern matches a directory, then the ! negates it to mean anything that is not a directory (so, a file). The '--include=*.jar' has precedence over the filter so .jar files (only) are included.

Comment: That was very useful, thks!Just to make sure I got it, you are filtering the command by saying to match everything that is not a directory, which means all the files.  And the `--include` takes care of making sure that only `.m` files are considered.  A last question, what if I were interested in copying **only** the files in that directory, without copying the entire directory structure?

Comment: Yes, match all files and hide them, except for .jar files. Not sure I understand your last question: do you mean flattening the tree structure? If so see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800989/copy-every-file-of-entire-directory-structure-into-one-folder Or do you mean copy the .jar files from directory A to dir B? Plain old 'cp' will do that for you, or 'rsync *.jar /path/to/new/dir'

Comment: Cool, thks again for your explanation.  I mean copy all (and only) the `.jar` files in a directory A to a directory B, without going in the sub-directories of A.

Comment: This is clearly not the correct answer to this question, I'm not sure why it was marked as accepted.

Comment: @Ryan It's not so clear to at least 44 upvoters. Why is this not the correct answer to this question?

Comment: @CivFan I think what Ryan wanted is the flattening of the directories (i.e. copy of all jar files from subdirectories to one folder). This is ambiguous in OP's question as he doesn't say if destination_dir should contain subfolders or be flat. I need it to be flat and question suggested by Sean above has a nice answer by Kaz that worked for me.

Comment: I had a permission issue, which I initially fixed by doing a sudo, then I realized where "/destination_dir" was in my file system :P

Answer (score 40):

If you don't need the directory structure only the jar files, you can use:

```
shopt -s globstar
cp **/*.jar destination_dir
```

If you want the directory structure you can check `cp`'s `--parents` option.

Comment: +1 for shopt globstar, I didn't know about either of those things, useful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `--parents` option. It does something slightly different to the posters requirement: It creates the directory structure *as far as needed for the files to copy*, not the whole directory structure. - Was exactly what *I* needed! :-)

Comment: `cp -rf --parents destination_dir` works perfectly

Answer (score 20):

If your find has an -exec switch, and cp an -t option:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec cp -t /destination_dir {} +
```

If you find doesn't provide the "+" for parallel invocation, you can use ";" but then you can omit the `-t`:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec cp {} /destination_dir ";"
```

Comment: If the user's not using GNU find, there will be `-exec` but not with the `+` command terminator.

Comment: Thanks, @glennjackman. Added a plusless solution.

Comment: @glennjackman -1. The + command terminator is defined by POSIX. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/find.html

Comment: @jordanm, hmm. On a Solaris 8 box at work, the first find in my path is GNU find 4.1, which doesn't have +. Guess I shouldn't take a 10 year old program as gospel.

Comment: @glennjackman :) 10 years old? But mine is only 4.4.2 - doesn't look so dramatically.

Comment: This doesn't recursively copy subdirectories.

Comment: @lreeder: It does for me. Gnu-find v. 4.4.2 - just tested.

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't work recursively for me. `find -version` says `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`. `find . -name "*.jar" -exec cp -t /destination_dir {} +` copies all files flatly to /destination_dir, but not their parent directories.

Comment: @lreeder: No, it doesn't copy the directories which wasn't part of the problem specification but `to copy all *.jar files from directory and all its subdirectories`.

Answer (score 8):

```
cp --parents `find -name \*.jar` destination/
```

from `man cp`:

```
--parents
       use full source file name under DIRECTORY
```

Comment: The OP tagged this "unix", not Linux. AFAIK, the --parents option to cp is Linux-only.

Answer (score 4):

```
tar -cf - `find . -name "*.jar" -print` | ( cd /destination_dir && tar xBf - )
```

Comment: Why do you use the B flag for the destination tar? The man page says only "reblock as we read". I haven't ever run across obvious issues without it in similar settings, but I'm curious.

Comment: @EduardoIvanec Reblock will make sure that the copy has happened correctly. http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/lpt/18_16.html. Also, from tar GNU docs, `If --read-full-records (-B) is used, tar will not panic if an attempt to read a record from the archive does not return a full record. Instead, tar will keep reading until it has obtained a full record`
But as you observed, it should run fine in most of the cases.

Comment: I had an issue with the first tar quitting early due to signal 13 (broken pipe) with this method. Only some of the files were copied.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to maintain the same directory hierarchy under the destination, you could use

```
(cd SOURCE && find . -type f -name \*.jar -exec tar cf - {} +) \
  | (cd DESTINATION && tar xf -)
```

This way of doing it, instead of expanding the output of `find` within back-ticks, has the advantage of being able to handle any number of files.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name \*.jar | xargs cp -t /destination_dir
```

Assuming your jar filenames do not contain spaces, and your `cp` has the "-t" option. If `cp` can't do "-t"

```
find . -name \*.jar | xargs -I FILE cp FILE /destination_dir
```