# Copy every file of entire directory structure into base path of another

Tags: linux, bash, find, directory, cp

I have a directory-tree with a lot of files in it. I'd like to copy all of those files into one new directory, but with all files located in the base of the folder.

So I have something like this:

```
    images
    ├── avatar.png
    ├── bg.jpg
    ├── checkbox.png
    ├── cross.png
    ├── datatables
    │   ├── back_disabled.png
    │   ├── back_enabled.png
    │   ├── forward_disabled.png
    │   ├── forward_enabled.png
    │   ├── sort_asc.png
    │   ├── sort_asc_disabled.png
    │   ├── sort_both.png
    │   ├── sort_desc.png
    │   └── sort_desc_disabled.png
    ├── exclamation.png
    ├── forms
    │   ├── btn_left.gif
    │   ├── btn_right.gif
    │   ├── checkbox.gif
    │   ├── input
    │   │   ├── input_left-focus.gif
    │   │   ├── input_left-hover.gif
    │   │   ├── input_left.gif
    │   │   ├── input_right-focus.gif
    │   │   ├── input_right-hover.gif
    │   │   ├── input_right.gif
    │   │   ├── input_text_left.gif
    │   │   └── input_text_right.gif
    │   ├── radio.gif
    │   ├── select_left.gif
    │   ├── select_right.gif
```

And I'd like something like this:

```
    new_folder
    ├── avatar.png
    ├── bg.jpg
    ├── checkbox.png
    ├── cross.png
    ├── back_disabled.png
    ├── back_enabled.png
    ├── forward_disabled.png
    ├── forward_enabled.png
    ├── sort_asc.png
    ├── sort_asc_disabled.png
    ├── sort_both.png
    ├── sort_desc.png
    ├── sort_desc_disabled.png
    ├── exclamation.png
    ├── btn_left.gif
    ├── btn_right.gif
    ├── checkbox.gif
    ├── input_left-focus.gif
    ├── input_left-hover.gif
    ├── input_left.gif
    ├── input_right-focus.gif
    ├── input_right-hover.gif
    ├── input_right.gif
    ├── input_text_left.gif
    ├── input_text_right.gif
    ├── radio.gif
    ├── select_left.gif
    ├── select_right.gif
```

I'm pretty sure there is a bashcommand for that, but I haven't found it yet. Do you have any ideas?

CS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you are looking for ways to flatten the directory

```
find /images -iname '*.jpg' -exec cp --target-directory /newfolder/ {} \;
```

`find` all files `iname` in case insensitive name mode.
`cp` copy once to `--target-directory` named `/newfolder/`.
`{}` expand the list from `find` into the form of `/dir/file.jpg /dir/dir2/bla.jpg`.

Comment: didn't work for me with "cp: illegal option -- -". Kaz's answer worked for me

Comment: @alexey I cant reproduce your error, what environment did you run it in?

Comment: oh you're right - I'm using OSX's (10.11.2) built in bash which is known to be out of date: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)

Comment: It doesn't work on alpine based docker also, am getting the following

`cp: unrecognized option: target-directory`

`BusyBox v1.28.4 (2018-07-17 15:21:40 UTC) multi-call binary.`

Answer (score 35):

```
find /source-tree -type f -exec cp {} /target-dir \;
```

Comment: this is truely the best solution. Is it possible that you breakdown the command and explain what which "operator" does? f.e -type? Would be very cool tho!

Answer (score 2):

On **zsh**:

`cp /source/**/* /destination`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd images && cp ** new_folder/
```

Comment: This solution response to the question correctly. She is very similar to the solution under Zsh. So, why -1 ???

Comment: It doesn't copy hidden files BTW