# How can i copy only header files in an entire nested directory to another directory keeping the same hierarchy after copying to new folder

Tags: linux, shell, cp

I have a directory which has a lot of header files(.h) and other .o and .c files and other files.
This directory has many nested directories inside. I want to copy only header files to a separate directory preserving the same structure in the new directory.

`cp -rf oldDirectory newDirectory` will copy all files.
I want to copy only header files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive copy of specific files in Unix/Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622883/recursive-copy-of-specific-files-in-unix-linux)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(cd src && find . -name '*.h' -print | tar --create --files-from -) | (cd dst && tar xvfp -)
```

You can do something similar with cpio if you just want to hard link the files instead of copying them, but it's likely to require a little mv'ing afterward.  If you have lots of data and don't mind (or need!) sharing, this can be much faster.  It gets confused if dst needs to have a src in it - this is, if it isn't just a side effect:

1. find src -name '*.h' -print | cpio -pdlv dst
2. mv dst/src/* dst/.
3. rmdir dst/src

Comment: Sounds good... I think cpio is what i was looking for esp. the -d option.

Answer (score 2):

this one worked for me:

```
rsync -avm --include='*.h' -f 'hide,! */' . /destination_dir
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9626253/1787109)

Answer (score -1):

```
cp -rf oldDirectory/*.h newDirectory
```

or something like (depending on the actual paths)

```
find oldDirectory -type f -name "*.h" -print0 | xargs -file cp file newDirectory
```

Comment: First solution copies .h files at depth 1 only. What if we have header files at depth 2 and 3 and so on.