# Copy specific files from a directory and subdirectories into a target folder in mac

Tags: java, command-line, copy, directory-structure, subdirectory

I have a directory structure in which i have some specific files (say mp3 files) organised directly or in subdirectories(upto n levels).
For example:

- Music Folder

  - a.mp3
  - folder2
  - folder3
  - b.mp3
  - c.mp3
  - folder4
  - d.mp3
  - folder5
  - folder6

    - folder7
    - folder8

      - e.mp3

Now, what i require is to copy all files (.mp3 file) from all the folders and subfolders into another target folder. So my target folder would be like this:

- targetFolder

  - a.mp3
  - b.mp3
  - c.mp3
  - d.mp3
  - e.mp3

I tried the answers from following questions:
[Recursive copy of specific files in Unix/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622883/recursive-copy-of-specific-files-in-unix-linux)

and [Copy all files with a certain extension from all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617016/copy-all-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-all-subdirectories/37012114), but got copied the same directory(and subdirectories) structure.

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java code, i achieved this as follows:

```
Path start = Paths.get("/Users/karan.verma/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music");
        int maxDepth = 15;
        try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(start, 
                    maxDepth, 
                    (path, attr) -> String.valueOf(path).endsWith(".mp3"))){

            List<Path> fileName = stream
                    .sorted()
                    .filter(path -> String.valueOf(path).endsWith(".mp3"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            for(Path p : fileName) {
                Path path = Paths.get("/Users/karan.verma/Desktop/TestCopy/"+p.getFileName());
                Files.copy(p, path,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cd "Music Folder"
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec cp {} /path/to/targetFolder \;
```